# Is it possible create a shortcut on vim to replace multiple times on a file?

Tags: vim, editor

I would like create a shortcut on vim to replace multiple times on a file, this a tool that I use several time.

Example of tool:

```
:%s/this.props/otherProps/gc
```

*This command will replace all this.props to otherProps and ask to confirm*

But I'm trying to convert this command in a shortcut like the example below:

```
// on .vimrc

noremap <leader>F :%s/$1/$2/gc
```

So in this case, I would every time a press `<leader>` + `F`, I type the first word, and after I press `tab` and type second word and after press enter.

I've put in the `$1` and `$2` as an attempt, but it doesn't work.

I tried to search some document about this, but I didn't find anything, maybe have some `word` more specific about that I don't know yet.

Comment: Thanks for @GiftZwergrapper for edit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst this doesn't do *exactly* what you asked for, it does get pretty close.

`noremap <leader>F :%s//gc<LEFT><LEFT><LEFT>`

This will type out the command `noremap <leader>F :%s//gc` but leave your cursor between the 2 slashes, ready to type in the stuff you want to find and replace.

So now you can just hit `<leader>F` and start typing `this.props/otherprops` and then hit enter. It does exactly what you want but instead of pressing `tab` you press `/`

Comment: No problem. I use this one to grab the word under my cursor and replace it:
`nnoremap <LEADER>r *yiw:%s/<C-R>"//gc<LEFT><LEFT><LEFT>`

Answer (score 5):

You could use a custom function by adding something like the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
function! Replace()
  call inputsave()
  let pattern = input('Enter pattern:')
  let replacement = input('Enter replacement:')
  call inputrestore()
  execute '%s/'.pattern.'/'.replacement.'/gc'
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>f :call Replace()<cr>
```

With this everytime you hit `<leader>f` the function is called. Which is then gonna ask you first for a pattern, then for a replacement and is then gonna execute the substitute command.

Comment: Good answer, but the first answer works well for me, but thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> esr getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'esr' ? '%s:\<end\>: & /*}*/:g' : 'esr'
```

This replaces end to end: `/*}*/`

You can add this to `gvimrc`; whenever `:esr` is typed, the above will be executed.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please format the code in your answer so that it becomes better readable.